# German translation appearing randomly for some text

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.5

I am using Qt 5.5.1 MSVC 2013 32 bit.

Recently I started seeing German text coming up in some of the error logs and UI widgets. I am not using internationalization of any sort. And this happens randomly for some text (at least I can't see any pattern, text appears in German for some reason randomly). eg.

[image]

Also,

[image]

Any clues what could be wrong ?

Comment: Did you try with the last version of Qt Creator? Or maybe using MSVC 2015.